# What happens if you deep-copy dictionary to itself?

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy

I just saw some code that says `data = copy.deepcopy(data)`.

- Does this work?
- What happens here?

Comment: That's not "to itself". The `data` variable is a separate thing from either the old or the new dict. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Nothing in the `copy` module provides any concept of copying objects *to* other objects.

Comment: In Python, the RHS is evaluated first, then assigned to the LHS. Nothing unexpected will happen in this example; you don’t need to be careful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will allocate new memory for the data. Try run this snippet code

```
import copy

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(hex(id(data)))
data = copy.deepcopy(data)
print(hex(id(data)))
```

Different memory address will be printed.